# gpg returns 2 when run from php

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, gnupg

I have this code which I can run without any problem on my `Amazon EC2` using `SSH`

```
echo mypassphrase | /usr/bin/gpg --batch --yes --always-trust --output daily_file/EZPNotif_1A_20160401.txt --passphrase-fd 0 daily_file/EZPNotif_1A_20160401.txt.gpg
```

but when I try to execute it using php exec like this

```
exec("echo mypassphrase | /usr/bin/gpg --batch --yes --always-trust --output ".$decryptedFiles[$i]." --passphrase-fd 0 ".$encryptedFiles[$i], $output, $return_var);
```

`$return_var` will return 2. And of course, the files aren't `decrypted`. What should I do?

Comment: `exec()` will call `gpg` directly without any shell interpretation (meaning the pipe won't work). Try using `system()` instead.

Comment: @Chris, I've tried using system() and it still returned 2...

Comment: Can you print the output of the command and check if it contains any errors?

Comment: Sorry @Chris, how do I do that?

Comment: @Chris funny, now it returns 255....